# set -eux instead set -x in Bash profile for global debugging

Tags: bash, debugging

When I work with Bash I love to do so with prominent debug mode, so each time I get a new machine I add to the end of `~/.profile` the code `set -x`.

I consider adding `eu` as well, so to have `set -eux` as a "best-practice'.

If I understand the [BR manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Set-Builtin.html) correctly

1. `e` gives me the benefit of not-executing code that would eventually return a non-zero (typically erroneous) output.
2. `u` - I didn't quite understand, the man says:

> Treat unset variables and parameters other than the special parameters
>   ‘@’ or ‘*’ as an error when performing parameter expansion. An error
>   message will be written to the standard error, and a non-interactive
>   shell will exit.

It sounds to me quite like `e` but also treating unsetted variables as error-causing and exits with a non-zero as well.

Is my understanding here accurate and `set -eux` is better than just `set -x` in general for someone seeking best "typical" debugging out there?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This is a matter of opinion, but I think `set -eu` is a bad idea for interactive use. Here’s what each one does:

- `set -e` causes the shell to exit whenever a [pipeline](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Pipelines.html#Pipelines), [list](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Lists.html#Lists), or [compound command](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Compound-Commands.html#Compound-Commands) exits with non-zero status;
- `set -u` causes the shell to exit whenever it attempts to expand a parameter which isn’t defined.

In an interactive shell, this means that any mistake in a command would cause the shell to exit! For example, a typo in a command name, or `rm` with an incorrect file name, or `echo $blah` with an incorrect variable name...

`set -e` and `set -u` can be useful when writing shell scripts. In particular, `set -e` avoids compounding errors: as soon as a command fails, the script exits, which can avoid trouble from subsequent commands which don’t run in the context they expect.

Compared to your explanations, note that `-e` doesn’t protect you from executing code which would return a non-zero status; the command has to execute for it to return a non-zero status.

Comment: `set -e` will only apply to the last command of a list.
`set -e; false && true; echo "yes"` will echo `yes`, but `set -e; true && false; echo "yes"` will not. See also https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/en/man1/set.1posix.html